# ClickHouse - Is there a possibility to make a query with JOIN to the DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, clickhouse

I have two tables to work with. The 1st one is MySql table containing categories and product_ids. Another one is Clickhouse table where I need to get date, product_id and sales. In result I need to have a table with columns category, week_number, sales. This means that I have to merge somehow these two tables and group sales by category and week_number.

```
1st TABLE: categories data
category  product_id        
Shoes     1368         
Bags      9837         
Books     7635 
Shoes     6479
...
```

```
2st TABLE: sales data
date        product_id   sales       
2021-08-11     1368       560.0 
2021-08-11     9837       419.9  
2021-08-12     7635       345.5
2021-08-13     6479       1015.5
...
```

A dataframe I would like to have as a result:

```
df: sales data aggregated by week_num and category
week_number   category     sales       
10             Shoes      7567899.0 
10             Bags       7567899.0  
10             Books      7567899.0
11             Shoes      7567899.0
...
```

It would be not a big deal to do one dataframe from mysql query, then to make another dataframe from clickhouse query, merge them and group the data the way I need. But the problem is in the second table, cause the period of my interest is half of the year and there are thousand of product sales for each date.

I was interested if I can make a dataframe from my first MySql table and then somehow join the data from it within my ClickHouse query to make it quicker and easier.
May be something like that:

```
SELECT category, toYearWeek(date) as week_number, sum(sales) as sales
FROM sales_data
JOIN **#SOME CODE TO JOIN THE TABLE WITH A DATAFRAME#**
ON sales_data.product_id = df.product_id
WHERE date BETWEEN '{start_date}' AND '{end_date}'
GROUP BY category, week_num"""
```

I am not sure if this possible, anyway many thanks to anyone who will give me a good advice.

Comment: But CH able to do JOIN with a table in mysql. And it's not related to Python/Jupiter https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/mysql/

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/mysql/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it! I didn't even have a thought it is possible.

Comment: @DennyCrane Thank you a lot, it worked just the way I needed.